# Extract an Icon from a binary .resources file

Tags: c#

We have created a binary .resources file called SharedIcons.resources that contains nothing but Icons and has been created by resgen.exe from a resx file. We want to use the icons contained within this .resources file in other C# applications, but I cannot fathom out how to get the icons back out, to use on e.g. form buttons etc.

I tried something like:

```
string resFile = "SharedIcons.resources";
ResourceManager resMan =  new ResourceManager(resFile, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
Image image = (Bitmap) resMan.GetObject("ID_ICON");
```

But receive the error:

```
System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 'Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "SharedIcons.resources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "WindowsFormsApp7" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.'
```

SharedIcons.resources is a file alongside the executable. Not really sure what I am doing wrong or how to achieve this, it seems like it should be easy. Is it possible to do this at design time & runtime? And if so, how?

Comment: and what documentation says about `ResourceManage`'s constructor's first string parameter? Did you at least read an exception? `Make sure 
 "SharedIcons.resources.resources"...` + brain = solution

Comment: Thanks Selvin, very helpful. Can I achieve this without embedding the resources file into the executing assembly and read Icons directly from the binary .resources file at runtime?

Comment: by loading Image directly from supported files .. look into documentation of Image class ... search for static methods

Comment: You'd need the ResourceReader class to dig the icon out of the .resources file.  This is in general a mistake, .resources files are build artifacts.  Always favor embedding the file so you get the benefit of a memory mapped file to load them.

Comment: Thanks Hans, this pointed me in the right direction. Selvin, your responses were patronising and unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, for a SharedIcons.resources (non embedded) file located alongside your program executable you can do the following:

```
var newResourceManager = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager("SharedIcons", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), null);
var ico1 = (Icon)newResourceManager.GetObject("ID_ICON");
```